# How to add custom, non-model fields dynamically to Django ModelAdmin or ModalForm?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to create custom fields for my modal in Django Admin. I have two models - Page and PageTemplate. PageTemplate stores all the needed custom fields for the Page and has a property `custom_fields = JSONField(default={})`. Page has a OneToOne relationship to PageTemplate. Page also has a `custom_fields = JSONField(default={})`. This property stores the values for the page. Here is my admin and form signature:

```
class PageAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    form = PageForm
    fields = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'parent', 'template', 'test']

class PageTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name', 'slug']
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    fields = ['name', 'slug', 'custom_fields']

class PageForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            if instance.template:
                custom_fields = instance.template.custom_fields
                                    # Add a test field so that it shows it in admin:
                self.fields['test'] = forms.DateField() 

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        exclude = ()
```

This system will work in the following way:

1. If a template is given to Page, it will read the `custom_fields` property of PageTemplate from the OneToOne relationship and display them with the given widgets in Page.
2. Then just get the values from Page's `custom_fields` property and populate the added Page Template `custom_fields` with the retrieved data.
3. Before save, these fields will do all the validations thanks to their types etc. During save, a JSON object will be created and it will be saved to Page's `custom_fields` property while ignoring all the non-Model fields.

At this time, I just want to display any field dynamically. But I get an error:

> Unknown field(s) (test) specified for Page. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class PageAdmin.

How can I make this work? Maybe I have progressed in the wrong direction, so please give me any kind of tips on how to proceed on this issue.

Thanks!

EDIT: Traceback

> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_form
>     639.             return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in modelform_factory
>     545.     return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/parler/forms.py" in **new**
>     316.         return super(TranslatableModelFormMetaclass, mcs).**new**(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in **new**
>     257.                 raise FieldError(message)
>
> During handling of the above exception (Unknown field(s) (test) specified for Page), another exception occurred:
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
>     541.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
>     57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
>     244.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
>     1440.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
>     67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
>     63.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in inner
>     30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
>     1367.         ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/parler/admin.py" in get_form
>     311.         form_class = super(TranslatableAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_form
>     642.                              % (e, self.**class**.**name**))
>
> Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/common/page/1/change/
>   Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (test) specified for Page. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class PageAdmin.

Comment: It looks like there is no "test" field in your Page model. Either you add it to your model which will be saved in the DB, either you add it to your PageForm form, then it won't be saved in your DB. Hope this help.

Comment: I added test field to `__init__` but it still gives me error. I can't hard code it as I want to create the fields based on JSON.

Comment: Where do you get that error? Show the full traceback.

Comment: I get that error when I am entering the page create or update from django admin. Please check my edit for traceback. **EDIT:** I forgot to mention. This error happens as if the field was not added through `self.fields`.

Comment: Like I said, this field should be added in PageForm or Page model. You are not supposed to add any code in \_\_init\_\_ except if you have good reasons.

Comment: But then I won't be able to add them dynamically through data. I have to hard code them because Page admin form fields will change based on PageTemplate.

Comment: I feel that having custom/dynamic fields is not the right architecture/solution. I might be wrong but it does not feel right to me. What is the reason of your solution ? What are you trying to accomplish exactly ?

Comment: A page is just a static page. It has a title and body. This works well for static pages but what if I want to have page that shows not just title and body? For example, I want to have a Contact page that has a map widget and specific values (phone, email etc) that will be rendered in a view. I can use EAV for these fields but to me using JSON is a much elegant solution from database and API perspective. I currently have the json field in the admin and I can fill it with data and API shows the data. Now all I want is to create an interface that fills this JSON without needing to see JSON field.